# horizontal scrolling of the block when scrolling the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have not found anything like this. I am writing at the call of the soul. Anyone who can help - help. Does not stop after reaching the last item. And also to optimize other resolutions. If you have any ideas, please help!

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.js-list')
const section = document.querySelector(".js-clients");

if (section) {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const widthList = list.offsetWidth;
    const halfHeightSection = section.offsetHeight;
    console.log(halfHeightSection)
    const scrollWin = window.scrollY + halfHeightSection;
    const sectionHeight = document.querySelector(".js-clients").offsetHeight + halfHeightSection;

    if (scrollWin >= section.offsetTop) {
      if (scrollWin <= (section.offsetTop + sectionHeight)) {
        let count = ((scrollWin - section.offsetTop) / sectionHeight) * halfHeightSection;
        list.style.transform = `translateX(-${count}%)`;
        console.log('scroll')
      } else {
        list.style.transform = 'translateX(-107%)';
        console.log('100%')
      }
    } else {
      list.style.transform = 'translateX(0%)';
      console.log('0%')
    }

  });

}
```

```css
.hero {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.another_section {
  height: 2500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
  max-width: 50rem;
}

.section {
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section__list {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .1s ease;
}

.section__item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #000;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.section__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="section js-clients">
    <ul class="section__list js-list">
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
      <li class="section__item"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="another_section"></div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here, and give more explanation of what result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by rotating the container element 90deg. Check this example:

```css
div{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  background: #111;
}

.horizontal-scroll-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:80px;
  max-height:500px;
  margin:0;
  background:#abc;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-80px);
  transform-origin:right top;
}
.horizontal-scroll-wrapper > div{
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
  background:#cab;
  transform:rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.squares{
  padding:60px 0 0 0;
}

.squares > div{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  margin:10px;
}

.rectangles{
  top:100px;
  padding:100px 0 0 0;
}
.rectangles > div{
  width:140px;
  height:60px;
  margin:50px 10px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#cab;
  transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(80px);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper squares">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  <div>item 5</div>
  <div>item 6</div>
  <div>item 7</div>
  <div>item 8</div>
</div>

<div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper  rectangles">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  <div>item 5</div>
  <div>item 6</div>
  <div>item 7</div>
  <div>item 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need at all, I need similarities
Locomotive scroll.